# GLFW won't compile on Atom. I have GCC and clang installed

Tags: c++, gcc, clang, glfw

I have GLFW installed in my documents and I have GL installed there as well, however, GL works and GLFW doesn't [Shown here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1cIef.png)
GLFW path [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fsUoy.png) 
new error [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q0AvR.png)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>

int main() {
  if(glfwInit()==false)
    cout<<"FAILED";
}
```

Comment: Check that the path containing `GLFW/glfw3.h` actually contains it, that it is accessible, and that it is provided as include search path to the compiler (`-I` switch).

Comment: I added a picture that hopefully can answer those questions because I am not sure

Comment: So the file is present and presumably accessible. But have you added `-I /home/jesse/Documents/glfw-3.2.1/include` to the compiler command line?

Comment: No, I don't know how to do that. Atom isn't an IDE so i installed a package that compiles it for me so there isn't a lot of settings

Comment: I don't know about that, but most likely there is a text field in the configuration/setting called `compiler command line` or `compiler options` or something like this, where the option can be added.

Comment: I think I just added that but now I have a new error

Comment: Yes, your code has multiple errors and in addition to the include search path you will also need to provide a library search path for GLFW (`-L` option). Errors in code are for example missing `#include <iostream>` (while the `stdlib.h` and `stdio.h` are unneeded), `cout` should be `std::cout`, etc. You should start with a simple course about the base language before you try using more complex stuff like graphics libraries.

Comment: Ok thank you I added the library path and i'm going to learn more c++ to hopefully understand better.